# Hadoop services turn off on one or more data nodes when running a Hive query

Tags: hadoop2

All the sudden, and after being working fine, now when I run a simple hive query like:

```
select MAX(temp) from weather where USAF=400010;
```

The Hadoop job information shows:

```
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 11; number of reducers: 0
2016-12-10 04:10:09,211 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-12-10 04:10:31,983 Stage-1 map = 14%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 37.03 sec
2016-12-10 04:10:33,049 Stage-1 map = 24%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 41.24 sec
2016-12-10 04:20:44,396 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-12-10 04:21:44,883 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-12-10 04:22:45,197 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-12-10 04:23:45,488 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-12-10 04:24:45,844 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
.
.
.
```

And it keeps on map = 0%.

More complex queries were finishing successfully.

**I have noticed that, for no reason to me, Hadoop services on one (or more) node out of the three data nodes I have, stops running when "map = 0%" starts to appear. So if I `jps` on those data nodes I get nothing.**

**What could be the reason? or at least, where can I find the log for that?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in the application logs. By default it can be found in http://your _name_node_url:8088/cluster. Click on the specific application and get the logs.

There might be the case that particular node is failing . can be due to various reasons like (memory , network, timestamp etc etc ).